# Having trouble understanding how the pre() function in Mongoose is working in this code snippet

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am learning how to make web apps with node.js. I have been following the tutorial provided by [Alex Young](http://dailyjs.com/2010/11/01/node-tutorial/).  I am having trouble understanding how the pre() function works in Mongoose.  I have read the Mongoose API documentation and understand that it is a way of "chaining" functions to an existing one, but I do not understand how it is actually working when I look at a code example (see below code snippets).

My question is what is going on in the here? There are three functions involved here (userSaved(), userSaveFailed(), and the password validation function defined in the pre() function).  How are these function related to each other in terms of order in which they run? Is the actual saving of the document into the database completed before userSaved() and userSavedFail() are run?

I admit that my lack of understanding understanding may be due to my lack of knowledge on javascript (I come from a PHP background), but I just can't follow what is going on in this code.

Modified save behavior define in models.js :

```
 User.pre('save', function(next) {
   if (!validatePresenceOf(this.password)) {
   // Through error if password fails validation.
   next(new Error('Invalid password'));
   }
   else {
     next();
   }
 });
```

Call to save data to database from app.js :

```
app.post('/users.:format?', function(req, res) {
    var user = new User(req.body.user);

    function userSaved() {
      switch (req.params.format) {
        case 'json':
          res.send(user.__doc);
          break;

        default:
          req.session.user_id = user.id;
          res.redirect('/documents');
      }
    }

    function userSaveFailed() {
      res.render('users/new.jade', {
        locals: { user: user }
      });
  }

  user.save(userSaved, userSaveFailed);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion,the function followed by "save", is the method which gets executed before the save function is called(as the function name "PRE" imply).

Answer (score 0):

The first function that is ran is user.save() passing in two callbacks, one for if user.save() completes without errors (userSaved) and another if it fails (userSavedFailed)

```
 User.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (!validatePresenceOf(this.password)) {
    // Through error if password fails validation.
    next(new Error('Invalid password'));
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
 });
```

This code is running a set of asynchronous functions in parallel, only returning a response once all the functions have completed. In this case it returns by calling a callback function (userSaved or UserSavedFailed). Which is called depends on whether there was an error during the process of any of the functions.

The [Async Module](https://github.com/caolan/async%20Async%20Module) also chains functions and allows them to run synchronously or in parallel and may provide some examples of how this is accomplished to help you better understand what's actually happening.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if I get this straight, the user.save() function is designed to take two callbacks as arguments and call either the first or the second depending on whether any errors occur during the save process. The function defined in User.pre() performs validation. If validation fails it will pass an error to the next function (which I assume is the actual 'save' function). In receiving this error, the 'save' function will not save the data and call the second of the two callback functions (i.e. userSavedFailed). Is that correct?